# How do I reduce extra unnecessary geometry from an imported model?

Tags: mesh, topology

[image]So, I have downloaded a couple of models like this one which has lots of unnecessary edges. I can dissolve those manually without affecting the overall shape of the model but this is a tiresome process.

Using decimate modifier reduces polygons in such a way that even a tiny input changes the shape of the model and has very little effect on those unnecessary edges.

Is there any other way to do this? Any addon or software?

Comment: i would just manually select all the unnecessary polygons and delete then and then remake the faces with little polygons using f

Answer (score 2):

Select all, Press <kbd>X</kbd> -> **Limited dissolve**